# How to use save games from iOS on PC and Android?

Tags: galaxy-on-fire-2

I played [Galaxy On Fire 2](http://www.galaxyonfire.com/de/galaxy-on-fire-2.html) on my iPhone and I bought the PC Version via Steam. Now I have a Android tablet and I'm curious to know how to transfer the save games to the PC and the tablet. Unfortunately a request to the customer support didn't help. They claimed that the exchange of save games just works for Apple devices through iCloud sync. What a shame! I already tried to just copy the data but on the PC the game didn't work properly when loading them.

Comment: Please upvote the question. If I get enough points I may set up a bounty.